# Is it possible to set an alias for a string?

Tags: linux, shell, replace, terminal, alias

As I'm so lazy, I don't want to type `192.168.1` everytime anymore. I tried this:

`root@kali:~# alias "ip" = "192.168.1"`

That does not seem to work. As an example off what I try to accomplish:

I don't want to type this anymore:

`root@kali:~# hping3 -S --scan 1-1000 192.168.1.133`

But instead shorter:

`root@kali:~# hping3 -S --scan 1-1000 ip.133`

Comment: Why not use an environment var?

Comment: Formatted content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `ip="192.168.1"` in your `~/.bashrc` file.
Relogin and you will be able to do: `ping $ip`

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, you cannot use an `alias` this way. But you could use an environment variable:

```
$ export ip='192.168.1'
$ hping3 -S --scan 1-1000 ${ip}.133
```